# is it possible to get .sass syntax highlighting in the monaco editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

I am pretty sure that there is no way to get .sass syntax highlighting in the monaco editor, just asking to confirm.

btw im using the monaco-editor-webpack-plugin.

Comment: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/ says there is Basic Syntax Colorization for SASS. Is that what you are looking for?